# Extract text from Swift string

Tags: swift

I have an array of strings and I want to extract only what's inside <>.

```
<div class=\"name\" title=\"&quot;User&quot; <John Appleseed>\">
<div class=\"name\" title=\"&quot;User&quot; <Bill Gates>\">
```

So the result I expect is ["John Appleseed", "Bill Gates"]

Comment: *"Is there any way to do this?"* – just ask yourself: do you see any logical pattern which you as a human would use to distinguish `<John Appleseed>` from `<div>` if you didn't know HTML?

Comment: From the top of my head, there are three ways here: **1)** `<John Appleseed>` is inside quotes. Will that always be the case? If so, you could make use of that. **2)** You could make a list of known html tags to distinguish between actual and seeming html tags **3)** parse the HTML and then find strings inside tags (which then aren't real html tags).

Comment: @LinusGeffarth - I was able to collect all div classes. No I have an array of '<div class=\"name\" title=\"&quot;User&quot; <John Appleseed>\">', how do I extract only what's inside "<>" in this case is John Appleseed

Comment: Try `<[\w\s]+>` as starting point using [regexpal.com](https://www.regexpal.com) (or similar). Depending on how similar the elements in the array are, that may be it already.

Comment: @LinusGeffarth the pattern you provided is not valid in Swift

Comment: That's why I told you to try it in the regex tester. When going to Swift, you need to escape the backslash: `<[\\w\\s]+>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have filtered out the correct rows and the structure of the string is the same you can use `lastIndex(of:)` and `firstIndex(of:)` functions to find the inner <> pair and then extract a substring from that

```
if let first = str.lastIndex(of:"<"), let last = str.firstIndex(of:">") {
    let name = String(str[str.index(after: first)..<last])
}
```

Example

```
let strings = ["<div class=\"name\" title=\"&quot;User&quot; <John Appleseed>\">", "<div class=\"name\" title=\"&quot;User&quot; <Bill Gates>\">"]

for str in strings {
  if let first = str.lastIndex(of:"<"), let last = str.firstIndex(of:">") {
    let name = String(str[str.index(after: first)..<last])
    print(name)
  }
}
```

produces

> John Appleseed
>   Bill Gates